# How to install aufs-tools in ubuntu 10.04

Tags: linux-kernel

Is there anyone knows how to install aufs-tools in ubuntu 10.04? Simply apt-get does not work.
Would you please provide me with some detailed informations?

Comment: This question belongs on [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I have worked with `aufs` and lucid, but have not used the `aufs-tools` package. What do you try to do? It looks like [the package was removed](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/i386/aufs-tools).

Just load the `aufs` kernel module and mount for using `aufs`.

```
modprobe aufs
mount -t aufs -o ...
```

to create a union fs.

Do you want to create a root file-system where the writes are volatile between reboots? That's what i did.